# mysql server stops while initializing hybris on mac os

Tags: mysql, sap-commerce-cloud

Just to share my experience of setting up Hybris for the first time on macOS.

Problem:
My hybris server and MySQL server got started without any issue, but as soon as I did an initialization on Hybris from HAC, mySQL server gets stopped after some time and initialization stuck in between. Tried this process multiple times.

I have tried different configurations of mySQL using my.cnf file but got no success.

Hybris version: 6.6.0.3
MySQL version: 5.7.28

Answer (score 0):

Got the final solution that worked for me, below is the set of configurations that i added in /etc/my.cnf file:

```
    [mysqld]
wait_timeout            = 6000
interactive_timeout     = 6000
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

max_connections=500
max_allowed_packet=1024M
innodb_file_per_table=0
thread_stack=500K
```

I hope this will help any newcomer setting up Hybris with MYSQL.

Cheers